# sorting list of decimals in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, floating-point

I have the following list that I'd like to sort:

`['104.900209904', '238.501860857', '9.59893298149', '362.470027924', '419.737339973']`

I used the "sorted" function to do it:

```
Block1_Video1 = sorted(Block1_Video1)
```

However, this is what I get:

```
['104.900209904', '238.501860857', '362.470027924', '419.737339973', '9.59893298149']
```

Whereas this is what I want (a list sorted numerically, taking decimal points into account):

```
[''9.59893298149', 104.900209904', '238.501860857', '362.470027924', '419.737339973']
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your list is a list of strings, not numbers.  It is sorting them alphabetically, not numerically.  That is why it is acting funny.  I'd post the answer but I see someone already bet me to it, I just wanted to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sorting needs to be based on the float values of the corresponding strings in the list.

```
Block1_Video1 = ['104.900209904', '238.501860857', '9.59893298149', '362.470027924', '419.737339973']
sorted(Block1_Video1,key=lambda x:float(x))
```

Or simply use

```
sorted(Block1_Video1, key=float)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your strings in numbers first, this is possible with the key-Argument of the `sorted` function:

```
Block1_Video1 = sorted(Block1_Video1, key=float)
```

or as you assign the new list to the same variable, you can also sort in-place:

```
Block1_Video1.sort(key=float)
```